# How to access Apache Archiva rest services using curl

Tags: apache, archiva

I installed Archiva 1.4-M4, and tried to access its REST API, beginning with the simple [ping service](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4/rest-docs-archiva-rest-api/resource_PingService.html), using curl;

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/restServices/pingService/ping
<html><body>No service was found.</body></html>
```

Perhaps some configuration needs to be set to enable the services, but I can't find anything in the [documentation](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4/adminguide/webservices/rest.html) that indicates such.  It does say there should be a .wadl file in the distribution, but I can't find one in the install directories.

How do I get started with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`http://localhost:8080/restServices/archivaServices/pingService/pingenter`

See wadl files:  `http://localhost:8080/restServices/`

If installed as root context! If not `http://localhost:8080/${yourContext}/...`